# How can i find the process using the most memory by SPID?

Tags: sql-server, spid

I want to  find the process using the most memory by SPID, is it even possible in SQL Server? If so what will be the query?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT mg.granted_memory_kb, mg.session_id, t.text, qp.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants AS mg
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(mg.sql_handle) AS t
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(mg.plan_handle) AS qp
ORDER BY 1 DESC OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```